# how do I specify a variable in cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & Variable & "" , "") in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The field in which the data should be inserted is actually dependent on the store which is active currently. For that reason I want the parameter be dynamic based on the case but I am not able to figure out how do I mention a variable inside the Parameter function as name of the field

Code:

```
 Dim whichListID = "Store1ListID"
 Str = "Insert Into Customer ([" & whichListID & "], [AccountBalance])"& 
 "Values(@" & whichListID & ",@AccountBalance)"
  cmd = New SqlCommand(Str, con2)  
  Dim Value as string="45675671 'Fine up till here

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("" & "@" & whichListID & "",Value )
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountBalance", 0)
 con2.Open()
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  con2.Close()
```

So my question is how do i write the following statement correctly:-

```
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("" & "@" & whichListID & "", Value)
```

Comment: The scary part here appears to be that this is open to injection.

Comment: but the parameter would be consisting field name not data

Comment: You can't parameterize column names. It seems odd to insert the column name as a column value too. Is that your intent?

Comment: @Far injection doesn't just happen at the point of raw concatenation of values, it can happen at any point; including when you define the object's name. An SP like this, for example, would be wide open: `CREATE PROC SelectTable @T sysname AS DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT* FROM ' + @T; EXEC @SQL;` `@T` isn't a parameter for a value, but an object name, but that doesn't mean it's injection safe.

Comment: start by NOT using [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) anywhere.

Comment: @Dan Guzman `You can't parameterize column names`, are you sure you cant? Theres nothing stopping me from calling an sp which has params, that can take column names to build what I want using dynamic sql...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, what I mean is that the column names in the executed SQL statement cannot be parameters.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, that is more appropriate and correct, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I put the following line of code which solved the problem

```
 Dim Field As String="@" & WhichListID
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Field , "45675671")
```